# How can I form a Levi-Civita 3x3x3 matrix easily in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'd specifically like to know how to create it without using for loops. Also, how could it be done for a general N-dimensional [Levi-Civita matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was bored so I took a twisted route. It does not answer the question since this is not "easy" but i'm sharing this since i had fun.

From the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) definition, you can build a function give you the value of the Cevi-Levita symbol from the indices:

```
LC_value = @(v) round(prod(prod(triu(repmat(v,[numel(v) 1])-repmat(v',[1 numel(v)]),1) ...
           ./repmat(factorial([1:numel(v)]'),[1 numel(v)])+tril(ones(numel(v))))));
```

This implements the general n-dimensional nested product definition. Be careful, the factorial function might lead to problems in high dimensions. The `round` function is there because you're doing floating point operations to generate integers.

The next step is to apply this function to all the possible indices combinations. Nevertheless, it is faster to apply it only to the permutations of `[1 2 3]`.

```
sites = perms([1 2 3]);
values = arrayfun(@(i)LC_value(sites(i,:)),(1:size(sites,1))');
lcMat = zeros(3,3,3);
lcMat(sub2ind(size(lcMat),sites(:,1),sites(:,2),sites(:,3))) = values;
```

That's it. It's working for three dimensions, and it should work for higher dimensions, although i haven't tested it.

Comment: Your method works to 4-d too. But failed at 5-d. Any particular reason?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a non-loop solution specifically for a 3-by-3-by-3 [Levi-Civita matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) that uses [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#f1-85511):

```
lcMat = zeros(3,3,3);
lcMat([8 12 22]) = 1;
lcMat([6 16 20]) = -1;
```

**EDIT:**

And here is a more general and succinct non-loop solution for an [N-dimensional Levi-Civita matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Generalization_to_n_dimensions):

```
[mats{1:N}] = ndgrid(1:N);
pairsIndex = nchoosek(1:N,2);
lcMat = sign(prod(cat(N+1,mats{pairsIndex(:,2)})-...
                  cat(N+1,mats{pairsIndex(:,1)}),N+1));
```

There is a trade-off, of course. Although it doesn't use loops, there are potentially large temporary variables created. The larger `N` is, the more prohibitive this memory cost will be.

Comment: i don't think it's the answer he was hoping for, but it fulfills the requirements.

Comment: @Adrien: It took me a bit longer to figure out a potential general solution, so I answered the simpler part of the question first. ;)

Comment: nice, gnovice! BTW, is there a simple way to show only the non-all-zero 2d matrices when printing out lcMat?

Comment: @Qiang: You can display all the 2D planes that contain non-zero values by doing this: `nzPlanes = reshape(any(any(lcMat,1),2),[],1); lcMat(:,:,nzPlanes)`

Answer (score 1):

I found at least two functions on File Exchange - [#1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9840-levi-civita-symbol) and [#2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26515-levicivita). Have you checked them? Both are using loops.

For just 3D matrix, you can input it directly and avoid loop.

It would be nice to include some kind of explanation of the topic into the question. Here is a link to Wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol